# Froala editor: Append new attribute to image tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, froala

I am trying to add a new attribute to an uploaded image. This attribute will contain the delete url for that image which will be used by the event **afterRemoveImage** in order to destroy that resource on the server side.

I have tried using **afterImageUpload** event, but I don't find the created image tag.

Which would be the proper event to use?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess that I just found the answer. I am sharing it for anyone else struggling with it. The event that I needed was ** imageInserted**. https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/events#imageInserted